# Is there a better way to phrase this if statement from having many possible conditions?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, p5.js

I'm making a code where I need to determine if a letter is a consonant or a vowel. I'm trying to find a way to simplify my if statement, but I don't know of any way except an if statement with multiple ||possible statements. Is there any way to do this where it encompasses all of the letters in one condition, for example: `if(myStr === 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u') {}`? I have other variables I haven't used yet, but here's my code:

```
class Word {
  constructor(x, y, str) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.str = str;
  }
  I
  //Find out the word's composition of consonants and vowels and divide word into sections
  divSect(word) {
    var newStr = this.str.split("");
    for(var i = 0; i < newStr.length; i ++) {
      if(newStr[i] === "a" || newStr[i] === "e" || newStr[i] === "i" || newStr[i] === "o" || newStr[i] === "u") {
        console.log("test");
      }
    }
  }
  
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex could work.

```
if (/[aeiou]/.test(newStr[i])) {
  console.log("test");
}
```

Comment: I haven't seen this before, but I'm guessing that this goes through each thing in the brackets and tests if it is equal to newStr[i], right?

Comment: @TheCodedMasterCubing that's correct, `[aeiou]` is a character class which matches any of the characters inside it

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`String.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```js
console.log('aeiou'.includes('a'))
console.log('aeiou'.includes('b'))
```

In your code you would write your `if` statement as

```js
if ('aeiou'.includes(newStr[i])) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: So I'd do if(newStr[i].includes('aeiou')) {}?

Comment: No, you'd do `if ('aeiou'.includes(newStr[i])) {}`, you want to check if the string `aeiou` includes the current character (in which case it must be a vowel)

Comment: Sorry, I guess that's what I meant - I accidentally switched them. Thanks for explaining!